# The calendar_style style requires a Date argument error when Using CCK as a date argument

Tags: entities, datetime, views

Can´t use a date CCK field when setting up a calendar as a view
When I want to save the view I´m getting this error message:

```
The calendar_style style requires a Date argument.
```

I´ve added the same CCK field to the fields so views would stop complaining about another error message that in the new versions of views was added..that the same argument has to be present on the fields

Still ..the date type of the CCK isn´t recognized as a valid date argument...
Works with node updated date though...

I have Drupal

```
Date 6.x-2.7
Calendar 6.x-2.4
Views   6.x-2.12
and Drupal 6.22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a calendar in Drupal 6, you should clone the default calendar views in order to create a new on instead of trying to make it from scratch ([Error when changin Date argument](http://drupal.org/node/407216)).

Have a look at these tutorials if you need some extra help:
- [Drupal Calendar Setup](http://vimeo.com/6544779)
- [How To: Create a Drupal Calendar](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-calendar)